# Multi-letter flags in c in command line

Tags: c, linux, command-line-arguments

I want to create multi-letter flag in c. For example -12 or -16 to put value 12/16 into variable n or -help to tell program to print help. I was aiming to use getopt().
Example of use
`./a.out -12`
or
`./a.out -help`

I tried

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int aflag = 0;
  int bflag = 0;
  int cflag = 0;
  char *cvalue = NULL;
  int index;
  int c;

  opterr = 0;

  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case '8':
        aflag = 1;
        break;
      case '12':
        bflag = 1;
        break;
      case '16':
        cflag = 1;
        break;
      default:
        aflag = 1;
        break;
      }

  printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cflag = %s\n",aflag, bflag, cflag);

  return 0;
}
```

but it completly doesn't work. I also thinked about iterating through argv array and comparing them to what I want, but I asking mainly about getopt() function.

Comment: `getopt(3)` only parses single character options. You'll probably have to write your own code to handle this.

Comment: Some OSes have `getopt_long()`, but it uses two dashes to start long options, not one.

Comment: You _may_ be able to use `getopt_long` or `getopt_long_only` and code (e.g.) `12` as a long option, like `-hello` (i.e. a string). You'd need to call the program with `--12` because long options are prefixed with `--` instead of `-` Or, roll your own loop: `for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) { char *cp = *argv; if (*cp++ != '-') break; if (strcmp(cp,"12") == 0) { bflag = 1; continue; } }`

Comment: thanks, getopt_long() worked for me

Comment: Your empty string as the third argument to `getopt()` won't work. You could specify `"0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:"` as part of the option string — that looks for a minus sign and a digit and expects at least one more digit for the value in '`optarg`. It isn't pretty and it isn't how it's intended to be used, but it can sometimes work. A number of POSIX command used to take `-<digits>` but have been modified to use some option letter and then the number (`tail -10` is better specified as `tail -n 10`, for example).  If your `getopt()` supports optional arguments (POSIX does not), you could use that.

Answer (score 0):

getopt() only processes single letter arguments. `getopt_long()`, `getopt_long_only()` support long option.

They all use the same design of a string that specifies the arguments you want to accept.  I suggest you just use the standard convention of a `-n` with a required value ("n:") and similar for the long options.

If you don't want enumerate all values then write your own parser along these lines:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = 42;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if(argv[i][0] != '-') break;
        if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-help")) {
            printf("help is on the way!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        // process all other arguments here
        char *endptr;
        long tmp = strtol(&argv[i][1], &endptr, 10);
        if(*endptr) {
            printf("n is not valid at \"%s\"\n", endptr);
            continue;
        }
        if(tmp < INT_MIN || tmp > INT_MAX) {
            printf("n is out of range\n");
            continue;
        }
        n = tmp;
    }
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
}
```

and example sessions:

```
./a.out -help
help is on the way
./a.out -12
n = 12
```